# How to name shops, cafes, entertainment centers in one word for good UX?

Tags: best-practice, wording, names

I'm not sure whether this is the right place to ask this kind of question.

We are launching a website for selling coupons. And there user can search coupons and companies(brands), like in google search there are sections like "All", "Images", "Videos" etc.

But in our case the "Companies" section will find shops, cafes, restaurants, cinemas, theatres, parks etc.
To name it "Companies" seems weird.

And I'm stuck on this. What is the best word for the section from point of UX?

I also thought about "Establishments", but it seems to be too long and not clear enough.

Comment: To answer it from UX point of view the question lacks a bit of context. But if I understand it correctly, the search is not for companies but for business types. Is "Businesses" the word you're looking for?

Comment: To be more clear, let's imagine that you can search brands that have coupons for sale on the website. There you can find, for example, Burger King, McDonalds, Starbucks, ... and buy their discount coupons like in Groupon

Comment: For what it's worth, I think any category grouping containing things as broad as "shops, cafes, restaurants, cinemas, theatres, [and] parks" might be too broad!

Answer (score 4):

Instead of looking for the kind of store or establishment, what can be helpful is to search the activity type:

- Leisure
- Free time
- Entertainment

Comment: To be more clear, let's imagine that you can search brands that have coupons for sale on the website. There you can find, for example, Burger King, McDonalds, Starbucks, ... and buy their discount coupons like in Groupon

Comment: I also thought about "Places". But companies may have several branches in the city and search result in the section will find only brands and if user selects the company then in another page there is information about branches

Comment: I need smth general to name the section

Answer (score 0):

It's best to find out what words your users are using when you're naming things.

Then make sure you're matching the words and phrases you use in your interface with the words and phrases your users are using when they're searching for these things.

This is good for user experience, good for the consistency and findability of your content, and good for SEO.

You could use a keyword research tool to explore search data to find out their most commonly-used words and phrases, or something like Google Search Console. You could also use your in-site searches, if you have access - but I think your site/app is probably not live yet.

Comment: Thanks. It is live. https://snips.uz